# How to print each element in each pdf different content using fpdf python?

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I use `for` loop to iterate each cell print i element but the content of each pdfs is same print only `0` index why doesn't print in pdf the iteration from `0` to `9` using `cell`?

```
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()

for i in range(10):

    pdf.cell(w = 100, h = 100, txt = '{0}'.format(i), border = 0, ln = 0,  align = 'c', fill = False, link = '')
    pdf.output('{0}.pdf'.format(i))

    # the output 0 in all pdfs
```

Comment: Once you call `Output()`, the PDF is finished and you can't modify it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `FPDF()` and `add_page()` I enter then inside the loop and worked me very well

```
 for i in range(10):
        pdf = FPDF()
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.cell(w = 100, h = 100, txt = '{0}'.format(i), border = 0, ln = 0,  align = 'c', fill = False, link = '')
        pdf.output('{0}.pdf'.format(i))
    
        # the output 0 in all pdfs
```